# Errors when reading content from URL - Cannot find any clue from logcat

Tags: android

I want to master parsing json content from url so I tried a small excercise. I created a small  app. My first step is to get content from url. I get stuck when the app "stop working" and there is no clue from logcat showing me where I am wrong.

Activity:

package tri.jsonparser;

```
//import...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn;
    String str;
    Button btn;
    TextView content;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textContent);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    url = new URL("http://thinktodo.net/LocationServiceSystem/index.php/location/getLocation?username=1");
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    Log.d("my tag", "connection ok");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    Log.d("my tag", "reader ok");
                    str = br.readLine();
                    content.setText(str);
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLat"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
        android:text="Get content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="Content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
04-22 16:24:42.365: E/cutils-trace(1456): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-22 16:24:42.421: E/memtrack(1456): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-22 16:24:42.421: E/android.os.Debug(1456): failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-22 16:24:42.737: E/cutils-trace(1467): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-22 16:24:42.789: E/memtrack(1467): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-22 16:24:42.789: E/android.os.Debug(1467): failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-22 16:24:43.093: E/OpenGLRenderer(1478): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-22 16:24:43.101: E/OpenGLRenderer(1478): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
04-22 16:24:43.145: E/OpenGLRenderer(1478): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-22 16:24:43.149: E/OpenGLRenderer(1478): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): Process: tri.jsonparser, PID: 1478
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at tri.jsonparser.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 16:24:45.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 16:24:48.121: E/InputDispatcher(547): channel '52a395b4 tri.jsonparser/tri.jsonparser.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: Running network operation on the main ui thread. You need to use a Thread or Asynctask. Code in button click must be in a thread

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` + `cannot find any clue from logcat` seriously?

Comment: @njzk2 I am newbie about android and I am studying it. I don't have much experience in reading logcat. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the connection inside a Runnable and run it on another thread. This is because Android does not let you perform network requests on your UI Thread (which is what you use by default in an Activity). Android does this as your network request may take a long time to return and the execution of your UI Thread stops ("blocks") until then.
Try replacing your btn.setOnClickListener() with the code below.

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Runnable r = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
            try {
                url = new URL("http://thinktodo.net/LocationServiceSystem/index.php/location/getLocation?username=1");
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.d("my tag", "connection ok");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                Log.d("my tag", "reader ok");
                str = br.readLine();
                Runnable uir = new Runnable(){
                 @Override
                 public void run()
                 {
                    content.setText(str);
                 }
                };
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(uir);
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        };
        Thread th = new Thread(r);
        th.start();
        }
    });
```

Once your request establishes a connection with the server, the content of your TextView will change.
EDIT: as @njzk2 pointed out, setting the contents of a TextView must take place on the UI Thread.

Comment: @njzk2 thankyou for pointing that out. The answer has been appropriately modified.

Comment: ok. removed the downvote as this is a working solution, however, a/ you should really consider asynctasks. b/ this question was asked and answered some million times, hence it should be closed as duplicated, not answered.

Comment: My apologies, I hadn't fully considered that. Will do.

Comment: Your answer give me a clue to solve the problem. I have to modify part of your code. Thank you.